# Convert CASE WHEN logic from SQL to EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a SQL query to determine whether a record is from a particular data company or not.

The SQL code goes like -

```
CASE WHEN COL_Category in ('A',B')
OR (COL_Name like  '%Apple%)
OR (COL_Name like  '%Ball%)
THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO'
```

And I am trying to get the logic to work in excel for the column "Yes/No?"

| COL_Category | COL_Name | Yes/No? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | Yes |
| B | Cat | Yes |
| C | Dog | No |
| C | Apple | Yes |
| D | Cat | No |

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. Answering for future reference.

A combination of IF(), ISNUMBER(SEARCH()), and OR() can be used to achieve the result.

[Find the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCO97.png)

Comment: You may try this as well, a much shorter formula `=IF(OR(TRIM(B4)={"A","B"},ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE({"Apple";"Ball"}),C4))),"Yes","No")` depending on your excel version may need to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`